# Replace particular string in csv python in a particular row and column

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, csv, replace

I have looked around but didnt quite find what i have problems with.

The question i have about is that in the csv files called registro_usuarios.csv that has the following data. Which has 6 rows and 6 colmuns

```
registro_usuarios.csv:
RUT,Name,LastName,E-mail,ISBN1,ISBN2
111,Pablo1,Alar1,mail1,0,0
222,Pablo2,Alar2,mail2,0,0
333,Pablo3,Alar3,mail3,0,0
444,Pablo4,Alar4,mail4,0,0
555,Pablo5,Alar5,mail5,0,0
```

Now how do can i make a def that allows me to replace a 0 below ISBN1 or ISBN2 for a given RUT?... For example, i want to replace the ISBN1 of the rut 333 for 777. Then after using the def, it should change the data in the csv like this. since rows and columns starts with 0,0 i believe then ISBN1 of the rut 333 is row 3 column 5 if im not mistaken.

```
registro_usuarios.csv:
RUT,Nombre,Apellido,E-mail,ISBN1,ISBN2
111,Pablo1,Alar1,mail1,0,0
222,Pablo2,Alar2,mail2,0,0
333,Pablo3,Alar3,mail3,777,0
444,Pablo4,Alar4,mail4,0,0
555,Pablo5,Alar5,mail5,0,0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pandas` too:

```
# recreate file
from pathlib import Path

Path('temp.txt').write_text("""RUT,Name,LastName,E-mail,ISBN1,ISBN2
111,Pablo1,Alar1,mail1,0,0
222,Pablo2,Alar2,mail2,0,0
333,Pablo3,Alar3,mail3,0,0
444,Pablo4,Alar4,mail4,0,0
555,Pablo5,Alar5,mail5,0,0""")

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('temp.txt', index_col=0)
df.loc[333,'ISBN1'] = 777
print(df)
# export example
df.to_csv('temp2.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way I could think of:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('data.csv') as f:
...      data = [r for r in csv.reader(f)]
... 
>>> data[3][4] = '777'
>>> with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
...     csv.writer(f).writerows(data)
...
```

As you mentioned you want to alter a row with an specific `RUT`. In that case I would use [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)/[`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) and a function to change the row based on the `RUT`:

```
import csv

def change_by_rut(csv_data, rut, new_isbn1):
    for row in csv_data:
        if row['RUT'] == rut:
            row['ISBN1'] = new_isbn1

with open('data.csv') as f:
    data = [r for r in csv.DictReader(f)]

change_by_rut(data, '333', '777')

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer_obj = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=data[0].keys())

    writer_obj.writeheader()
    writer_obj.writerows(data)
```

Comment: thanks, this has given me something to use. I will now try and make the code.